# jquery quicksand wired jumping

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-plugins, quicksand

I'm using a jQuery quicksand plugin in some sites and I use it in some tutorials to automatically sort the `li`s by type.

My website uses the plugin in two places:

http://www.adygraph.co.il/index.php/2012-07-12-15-50-40

http://www.adygraph.co.il/index.php/customers

In both cases the plugin works great, except the animation jumps. I've tried many solutions but is still happens.

There have been more errors just the height of the UL is not changed true just changed in *5 from the height it should be.

Can anyone help please?

Comment: http://razorjack.net/quicksand/ r u trying this ?

Comment: @g.e.manor , clarify please what is the problem?

Comment: @rahularyansharma of course i'm try to check the home page of the plugin.

Comment: @caligula the problem is when you click on some menu tag in the top is taking all the LI's to the 0 value on the left and is jumping back to the top or side.

in the first link i'd gave is just make one column in the left side and jump it to the true place

and in the second link i gave is jump to place of the top - left LI and jump to the true place

and the other problem is in any "page" (means sort group) they gone it's make very high height

Comment: @g.e.manor how it is supposed to behave?

Comment: @caligula like in this link [go to the demo](http://razorjack.net/quicksand/)

Comment: @g.e.manor    Do you know that you have an error `ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined var $K2 = jQuery.noConflict();` at k2.js (line 9)

Comment: yes, of course. is not happened cause of this...